# How to get List from Visualforce Component Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, email-template

I have a `visualforce component` which is used in an `email template` to display a list of related items.

**Visualforce Component**

```
<apex:component controller="LeadProductsController" access="global">

    <apex:attribute name="parentId" type="Id" assignTo="{!leadId}" description="" />
    <apex:attribute name="products" type="Lead_Product__c[]" description="" />

    <table style="width:500px" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <thead style="background-color: #003366; color: #ffffff;">
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>QTY</td>
            <td>Sales Price</td>
            <td>Total Price</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!products}" var="p">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!p.Product_Name__c}</td>
                    <td>{!p.Product_Code__c }</td>
                    <td>{!p.Quantity__c}</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</apex:component>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public without sharing class LeadProductsController {

    public List<Lead_Product__c> products { get; private set; }

    public String leadId;

    public void setLeadId(Id leadId) {
        this.leadId = leadId;
        products = [SELECT Id, Product_Name__c, Product_Code__c, Quantity__c FROM Lead_Product__c WHERE Lead__c = :leadId];
    }

    public Id getLeadId() {
        return leadId;
    } 
}
```

I then use the component in the email template like this:

```
<c:LeadProducts parentId="{!relatedTo.Id}" ></c:LeadProducts>
```

I've not used `visualforce component`'s before, so I suspect I am doing many things wrong, but I cannot find a decent example of what I am trying to achieve.

How should I get a List of data from a controller when using a `visualforce component`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three glaring problems which don't have anything to do with the error:

1. Your attribute `name` and `assignTo` use the same name.

   - You have to use different values, or you should get a compile fail.
   - See also: [How to solve the apex:attribute and assignTo naming conflict?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/139780/2995)
2. Your query selects only `Id`.

   - Make sure you actually pull all the fields you need.
3. You make your query in your constructor.

   - Data retrieval needs to move to your `leadId` setter.
   - The constructor fires before this setter and as currently written will use `null` as the filter value.

Now for the actual cause:

1. Your `products` Apex variable is not an **`attribute`**.

   - Add `{ get; private set; }` to the end of the line:

     ```
     public List<Lead_Product__c> products { get; private set; }
     ```
   - Always use a private setter unless you actually want the page to write to this variable.
2. You have included `products` as a conflicting `<apex:attribute>`.

   - Simply remove this line from your markup:

     ```
     <apex:attribute name="products" type="List" description="" />
     ```
   - You set the `type` as `List`, which I assume implicitly converts to `Object[]`.
   - If you needed this `<apex:attribute>`, you would change the `type` to `Lead_Product__c[]`

Comment: Thank you! that was super helpful. I was able to deploy my code. Alas, nothing actually appears in the email. I've updated the code example in the question. any ideas what might be the issue now?

Comment: Take a closer look at what I recommend for fix 2. @Robs